# PYSPARK : How to work with dataframes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dataframes

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc = SparkContext()
sql = SQLContext(sc)

df1 = sql.createDataFrame([("Mark", 68), ("John", 59), ("Mary", 49)], ['Name', \
'Weight'])

df2 = sql.createDataFrame([("White", 68), ("Smith", 59), ("Gary", 49)], ['Name', \
    'Weight'])
```

Now I want to randomly choose n = 2 (can be any number) pairs from the weight columns and create the following pairs, each pair consist of two unequal weights:

```
(68, 59)
(49, 68)
```

then I want to choose from df1 only those with weight 68 and 49, and from df2 only those with weight 59 and 68 and create another dataframe:

```
df3 = sql.createDataFrame([("Mark", 68, "Smith", 59), ("Mary", 49, "White", 68)], ['Name1', \
    'Weight1', 'Name2', 'Weight2'])
```

I'm working with big data. Given n, I first need to generate n pairs and then create the final dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> df1.where(df1['Weight'].between(68, 59)).union(df2.where(df2['Weight'].between(49, 68)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can have any number of pairs, i.e., given n, I first need to generate n pairs and then create the final dataframe.